# How to create exportable links to code lines using eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to ask my co-workers Alice and Bob specific questions about particular lines in code, e.g. com.example.HelloWorld.java:l.435. It would be nice if I could take some links out of eclipse, mail them in text form to another developer (also using eclipse) and go over to the co-worker and talk about those lines (without manually going to com.example.HelloWorld.java:l.435), but have some clickable link instead.

I know the bookmarks feature of eclipse, but I don't see a how to insert bookmarks.

*Edit*: I think I'm going to create a plug-in to make bookmarks create a fake exception stacktrace, which can be inserted into stack trace console. Has the benefit that the receiver can use it without installing something. [added code-review tag]

Comment: I'm kind of vague on the product details so I'll comment instead of answer.  What you're getting at is one of the core concepts behind IBM Rational's Jazz/Concert (?) which tries to bring collaboration to teams of Eclipse users.  Having said that, it's probably a much more heavy weight solution than what you're looking for.  I agree with @E-Riz that this would be a cool plugin, although it would be a lot more fun to write than market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way built-in to do that kind of thing, but it's an interesting idea for a plugin. Have you tried searching in the Eclipse Marketplace (available from the Help menu) to see if there's anything close?

An alternative that might meet your productivity need (thought not your specific feature request), is real-time shared editing via the [DocShare feature of ECF](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin). If your entire team were to set this up, you could use it to do a shared editing session with teammates.